# How to workaround bootstrap.pypa.io while installing openstack? It's not available

Tags: python, pip, openstack

I am trying to install openstack first time, as described on official website http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/

bootstrap.pypa.io is not available (i am not able to ping it).

It is possible to workaround it somehow?

```
~/devstack/tools/install_pip.sh:87:install_get_pip
~/devstack/tools/install_pip.sh:47:die
[ERROR] ~/devstack/tools/install_pip.sh:47 Download of get-pip.py failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because you don't have permission on folder "devstack", you should execute:

`sudo chmod -R 777 devstack`

in fact I was having the same problem and I solved it with last command.

A+